# Transfer learning training accuracy starts from a fixed value

Tags: keras, tensorflow, transfer-learning

I am training a transfer learning model using `tensorflow.keras` library for image classification. I am dealing with 7 classes. I have used several pre-trained models trained on 'imagenet'. For example, I am using `Xception` and unfreezing last 30 layers. When I replace the last layer with `softmax` layer, the training looks reasonable. The model summary looks like:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
xception (Model)             (None, 5, 5, 2048)        20861480  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 7)                 14343     
=================================================================
Total params: 20,875,823
Trainable params: 8,990,679
Non-trainable params: 11,885,144
_________________________________________________________________
Number of layers in the base model:  132
Number of trainable layers in the full model:  3
```

The training for the first two epochs looks like (The training accuracy starts from a low accuracy (10% or so)):

```
Epoch 1/12
525/525 [==============================] - 190s 362ms/step - loss: 0.7438 - accuracy: 0.7314 - val_loss: 0.3813 - val_accuracy: 0.8648
Epoch 2/12
257/525 [=============>................] - ETA: 1:28 - loss: 0.4986 - accuracy: 0.8182
```

### Problem

The problem starts, when I add one or more new layers before the final `softmax` layer. The training accuracy starts from exactly **85.71**. **It does not matter how many layers I add or whatever base model I use. The training accuracy starts exactly from 85.71, and after the first epoch, I get a very high accuracy (almost 94-95) for validation set**. Within a few epoch, the validation accuracy get over 98%. **But when I test it on a separate validation set, the performance is actually worse compared to model described earlier**.

For example, the model summary is:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
xception (Model)             (None, 5, 5, 2048)        20861480  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1024)              2098176   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 7)                 7175      
=================================================================
Total params: 22,966,831
Trainable params: 11,081,687
Non-trainable params: 11,885,144
_________________________________________________________________
Number of layers in the base model:  132
Number of trainable layers in the full model:  5
```

The training epochs looks like:

```
Epoch 1/12
525/525 [==============================] - 191s 363ms/step - loss: 0.1902 - accuracy: 0.9225 - val_loss: 0.0971 - val_accuracy: 0.9640
Epoch 2/12
 58/525 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2:38 - loss: 0.1351 - accuracy: 0.9470
```

I change the base model with different models, add/remove layers before the `softmax`, but the training accuracy always starts from 85.71.

Comment: Is it possible that 85.71% of your training data belongs to a single class? My first thought would be that all your models start out just predicting the majority class, which will have a constant accuracy regardless of the underlying model. Somewhat suspiciously, 85.71 happens to be 1-(1/7), where 7 is your number of classes - could you be predicting "not class X" correctly for most samples? That number seems oddly specific to be unrelated to your number of classes.

Comment: Nope, 7 classes is distributed like 2778, 3899, 4072, 1385, 3256, 1421, 1159 (training set). The same settings works fine when I do not add extra layer before the softmax layer.

Comment: "85.71 happens to be 1-(1/7)" that's actually a very good observation. Let me think, what must be the reason for it.